# OpenLayers: How to only pan map enough so feature is in view

Tags: openlayers, pan

When I put a feature on the map, I want to make sure it's in view.

I am currently using panTo() and the feature's centroid as a way to do this. However, this moves the map to be centered on the feature every time. This can make a very jittery map when features are nearby.

What I'd like is something where the map pans just enough to ensure the popup is in view (e.g. at the edge of the map vs. centered). And, if the feature is already on the map...don't pan.

Here is the code that generates the feature (NOTE: This is in a high-frequency loop that rapidly adds/remove features to create an animation):

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection(geometries), {
                        "color" : color,
                        "strokeOpacity" : settings.lineOpacity,
                        "fillOpacity" : settings.fillOpacity,
                        "label" : ""
                    });

layer.addFeatures([ feature ]);
setCenter(lon, lat);
```

And, here is the code for setCenter:

```
setCenter : function(lon, lat) {
    chMap.map.panTo(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(
            lon, lat
        ).transform(chMap.EPSG4326, chMap.EPSG900913)
    );
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it is the popup on the feature and not the feature that you want to ensure is in the view? And, if so, the whole of the popup needs to be in view, or just the anchor point?

Comment: Also, I assume you are using the featureadded event of the layer to which you are adding the feature to call panTo from?

Comment: Hi John - It is the feature itself that I would like to ensure is in view. Sorry for the confusion with popups. The panTo call is done after the layer.addFeatures() call.

Comment: Hi, does the feature need to be fully in view or partially. Can you post a bit of code for what you have done so far for the add feature and pan to parts?

Comment: added code snippets to original post. I'm wondering if logic within setCenter that checked to see if the lon/lat was within a certain distance of the map center would work (e.g. "if (distance > 80% to edge of screen) setCenter")

Comment: Added the following & it's better:
 if (!feature.onScreen()) {
  chMap.setCenter(lon, lat);
 }

Comment: Could you not just simply call feature.geometry.getBounds() and compare with map.getExtent()

Comment: Yes. I think that's what the onScreen() method of Feature is probably doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps others, here's the final code I ended up with to allow "following" of features on a map:

```
if (!map.getExtent().containsBounds(feature.geometry.getBounds(), false, true)) {
    chMap.setCenter(lon, lat);
}
```

The use of containsBounds() ensures that the entire feature is visible. The onScreen() method that was originally tried would not move the map if even 1 pixel of the feature was on the screen.

Hat tip to John Barça for his help